# How to disable Usb port?

Tags: 10.10, usb, usb-drive, devices

I am using Ubuntu 10.10. I want to disable my `usb port` due to some resign.
 so how i can disable my `usb port` and after that how i can enable it..

Comment: Do you want to disable USB storage devices?  Why are you still using such an old Ubuntu?

Comment: My answer only applies for a specific set of circumstances.  Why is it you want to disable a usb port, for what type of device, and are you trying to disable all usb ports or just one?

Comment: @david6 10.10 is not that old.  Less than two years ago, after all.  Some institutions are still using 8.04, which is a LTS; desktop support for it just ended last year, with server support ending now.

Comment: Define "disable". Do you want to remove the power or make Ubuntu ignore any USB device?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, although may cause other issues:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "blacklist usb-storage" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf'
```

Source:

- http://www.ossramblings.com/disabling_usb_storage_in_linux

Comment: how can we re enable it via command line??

Comment: Edit file **`/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`**, to remove line which that this added. ie. "blacklist usb-storage". You could use **vim** or **gedit**, from the command line. eg. **`sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`**

Comment: thanks , yeah it will work for sure , but cant we do it directly via terminal

Comment: @Sushantp606 We can! `awk '!/pattern/' file > /tmp/temp && sudo mv /tmp/temp /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Just rename storage to storage-old:

mv /lib/modules/3.2.0-35-generic-pae/kernel/drivers/usb/storage /lib/modules/3.2.0-35-generic-pae/kernel/drivers/usb/storage-old

Comment: change the kernel revision with the kernel ver. you have

Answer (score 0):

You're not being very specific.

List the USB modules currently loaded:

```
lsmod | grep usb
```

You can unload the modules with

```
sudo rmmod usb_storage    # for disks
```

Be carefull, you can easily lock yourself out if you're using USB keyboard/mouse and remove the usbhid module.

Answer (score 0):

This is not strictly an Ubuntu or Linux solution, but you could go into the bios of the computer and disable the usb ports from there.

Some computers will allow you to select which ports to disable (HP).

You can then also password protect the bios to ensure they are not just switched on again.

You may also want to pay attention to what usb input devices (keyboard / mouse) you have before disabling usb.